# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing but it present in the header

Tags: javascript

I need read to read remote content. I read that should be send header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I did that but still get this error. Here is script code

```
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://bbc.co.uk',
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
            success:function(json){
                // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
                alert("Success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

I see Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the sent headers. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be getting this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It says that the header is missing from the requested resource, which is what you get in the **response**.

You are putting it in the **request**, where it does nothing useful. Your JavaScript can't give itself permission to access other servers. The server you are trying to access has to give you permission.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `

```
headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
```

in PHP file.